# Jackson dependency issue: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory

Tags: java, maven, jackson, yaml, dependencies

I'm trying to import the Jackson YAML packages, but even after importing the dependencies correctly, it still errors that JsonFactory is missing. I'm currently using Maven to import dependencies.

Here are the dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have googled a lot about this problem, but I haven't found a solution yet.

And here is my code :

```
package dev.test

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestSave {

    public static boolean Save(TestData data) throws IOException {

        List<TestData> saved_data = new ArrayList<TestData>();

        saved_data.add(data);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    
        mapper.writeValue(new File("some_yaml_file.yml"), saved_data);

        return true;
    }
}
```

(The custom classes are predefined in other files)

Also, I'm not sure that using custom classes with Jackson is valid, but my plan here is to fix the dependency issue first.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed JsonFactory in your lib. please check on it first by searching this class by maven in your dependency. Make sure your dependency version is competible.

Comment: Since it should be included in com.fasterxml.jackson.core, i should already have the dependency.

And importing it with "import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;" unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).